# Why does my first autocomplete option disappear when I type more letters of it?

Tags: google-search

Say I am searching for something on Google. I type in "extr" and I see an autocomplete for a website I have visited that includes the word "extra" in the URL. Then I type the "a" to complete the word "extra" and the autocomplete is replaced by other things. Why would this happen? If I were programming an autocomplete, I would think typing one more letter towards it would make it more likely, not less. Is it because they think you've already had the opportunity to click it?
I find it very frustrating because I type quickly and by the time I press enter the page I wanted to go to has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

well Google autocomplete is a tool that is designed to help people complete a search they were intending to do, **not to suggest new types of searches** to be performed [[1]](https://www.blog.google/products/search/how-google-autocomplete-works-search/), since the suggestions of `extr` for you is static but predictions of `extr` is depending on many other tools(e.g. the way and even the speed of your typing), this behaviour happens.